# Unable to create a line graph in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

2nd day of using Pandas for analytics and I'm now trying to take advantage of its plotting functions. I'm having issues with creating a line graph from a data frame that I got after summing a column that was grouped by the date (in years).
The plot I want should display growth of the amount of orders throughout a year, so the date should be X axis and the orders should be Y axis.

My imports are as follows:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot
import seaborn as sns
```

I have a main data frame with all of the information, from that df, I made another one containing just the sum of a column.

```
ordersYears = rawData.groupby(rawData['Date'].dt.year)['Total Records'].sum();
ordersYears.set_index('Date')['Total Records'].plot();
```

However, I get the error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'`
And if I try to check out ordersYears.index I get

```
Int64Index([2018, 2019], dtype='int64', name='Date')
```

So it seems that this is not properly being recognized as a date. FYI the date column in the main dataframe IS datetime, I explitly converted it to that format and the process to create the other data frame wouldn't work if 'date' wasnt datetime.

Any ideas about whats going on?

Comment: What does the error message have to do with dates? If you ever want to check data types, you can use the `.dtype`/`.dtypes` attribute.

Comment: Why do you need to `set_index`? you can just do `ordersYears.plot()`.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile because I figured that if it was giving me that error and the date was being read as an int that it could be the cause of the problem. Also another type of call gave the error as just 'dates'.

Comment: @QuangHoang I was experimenting with tutorials. what is setindex for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `pd.series`, you need to use [`series.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html). `set_index()` is for `pd.DataFrame`. Also, you won't need to select a column (a `series` has only one column).

```
ordersYears.reindex(<the values you want as index>).plot()
```